# Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector' shows when i access using angular application using IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I am having an angular app which is working fine with ie11 when using the machine name to access it. But when using the F5 url to access the angular app, i am getting the below error

Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector'
File: angular.js, Line: 3, Column: 12281

Kindly advice. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this on an intranet? If so (or for other reasons), IE may be defaulting into IE7 compatibility mode (and IE7 doesn't support `querySelector()`).

Comment: Yes. This is on intranet. But the same code is working fine when i am accessing from localhost or with machine's ip name. The issue starts when i am using a F5 url or server name? Why this is happens?

Comment: Because IE is weird. I don't know what rules it uses to decide what is "intranet" and what isn't (you could google that), and I don't understand why MS thought it was a good idea to default into compatibility mode at all. The menu has a "Compatibility View Settings" option where you might be able to turn this off (on a per-computer basis), and you can use the Dev tools to check the settings of the current page. You can add a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` tag as the first thing in your `<head>` and it tells IE *not* to switch to an old compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Change the compatibility level of intranet site to edge or ie-11. Then it will work. 
(or) Uncheck the option "Display intranet site in the compatibility View"

[Internet setting option]--> the gear icon.